# Problem with button CreatePrizeButton_Click

Tags: c#, .net, messagebox

When I start the program, unfortunately, after not entering data and pressing the "Create Prize" button, I do not receive the message "This form contains incorrect information. Please check and try again." What am I doing wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using TrackerLibrary;

namespace TrackerUI
{
    public partial class CreatePrizeForm : Form
    {
        public CreatePrizeForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void CreatePrizeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ValidateForm())
            {
                PrizeModel model = new PrizeModel(
                    placeNameValue.Text,
                    placeNumberValue.Text,
                    prizeAmountValue.Text,
                    prizePercentageValue.Text);

                foreach (IDataConnection db in GlobalConfig.Connections)
                {
                    db.CreatePrize(model);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ten formularz zawiera błędne informacje. Proszę sprawdzić i spróbować ponownie.");
            }

        }
        private bool ValidateForm()
        {
            bool output = true;
            int placeNumber = 0;
            bool placeNumberValidNumber = int.TryParse(placeNumberValue.Text, out placeNumber);

            if (placeNumberValidNumber == false)
            {
                output = false;
            }

            if (placeNumber < 1)
            {
                output = false;
            }

            if (placeNameValue.Text.Length == 0)
            {
                output = false;
            }

            decimal prizeAmount = 0;
            int prizePercentage = 0;

            bool prizeAmountValid = decimal.TryParse(prizeAmountValue.Text, out prizeAmount);
            bool prizePercentageValid = int.TryParse(prizePercentageValue.Text, out prizePercentage);

            if (prizeAmountValid == false || prizePercentageValid == false)
            {
                output = false;
            }

            if (prizeAmount <= 0 && prizePercentage <= 0)
            {
                output = false;
            }

            if (prizePercentage < 0 || prizePercentage > 100)
            {
                output = false;
            }

            return output;

        }
    }
}
```

Hi

When I start the program, unfortunately, after not entering data and pressing the "Create Prize" button, I do not receive the message "This form contains incorrect information. Please check and try again." What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try using the debugger to a) make sure the click event is called, and if so b) why is the code not working.

Comment: @stuartd how can i use the debbuger to check a point a) ?

Comment: Add a breakpoint on the line `if (ValidateForm())`

Comment: I add and run. Unfortunately any effects.

Comment: If the breakpoint isn’t hit, then the click event probably isn’t being called. So I suggest you check it’s wired up correctly.

Comment: @stuartd It's ok? https://ibb.co/Z2jt1DZ

Comment: Make sure your button is properly binded to this function, in the form.cs graphic view. Also, try to write a message in the message box at the start of your createPrize_click() function. If this message doesn't appear it means your button is not linked to this function as @stuartd said.

Comment: @snus74 how to check them?

Comment: @norbertb you go to the graphical interface, double click on the button, it should bring you to the code linked to it